# Raycast used to stop player from going through wall only working half the time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have a project that I'm working on that uses a raycast to detect walls to prevent the player from going through a wall. In this project I have a script that handles all of the camera movements. The user can control the camera similar to the scene viewer in unity. I am using the same raycast method for preventing the user to go forward and it works everytime for the most part, but when I try to use the same method when the user moves like panning left or right it only works about half of the time. If you keep moving into a wall eventually you will go through. If anyone has any suggestions to improve how I am doing this or has a better method I would really appreciate it.

```
    //if the middle button is activated and player moves it left or right
    if (horizontalTranslation.isActivated())
    {
        //this will move the camera left or right when horizontal translation is activated  
        float translateX = Input.GetAxis(mouseHorizontalAxisName) * horizontalTranslation.sensitivity;
        transform.Translate(translateX, 0, 0);
        //variables used for the raycast
        origin = transform.position;
        Vector3 eLeft = -GetComponent<Camera>().transform.right;
        Vector3 eRight = GetComponent<Camera>().transform.right;
        RaycastHit hitLeft;
        RaycastHit hitRight;
        //this will send a raycast right if player moves camera right
        if (translateX > 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("right");
            if (Physics.SphereCast(origin, sphereRadius, eRight, out hitRight, maxDistance, layerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal))
            {
                //sets variable to position before hitting wall
                Debug.LogWarning("right initial hit " + hitRight.distance);
                if ((hitRight.distance < 5) && (hitRight.distance > 1))
                {
                    originalRayPos = transform.position;
                    originalRayRot = transform.rotation;
                    Debug.LogWarning("right set " + hitRight.distance);
                }
                //uses set variable to reset position back after hitting the threshold
                if (hitRight.distance < 1)
                {
                    transform.position = originalRayPos;
                    transform.rotation = originalRayRot;
                    Debug.LogWarning("right use " + hitRight.distance);
                }
            }
        }
        //this will send raycast left if player moves camera left
        if (translateX < 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("left");
            if (Physics.SphereCast(origin, sphereRadius, eLeft, out hitLeft, maxDistance, layerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal))
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("left initial hit " + hitLeft.distance);
                if ((hitLeft.distance < 5) && (hitLeft.distance > 1))
                {
                    originalRayPos = transform.position;
                    originalRayRot = transform.rotation;
                    Debug.LogWarning("left set " + hitLeft.distance);
                }
                if (hitLeft.distance < 1)
                {
                    transform.position = originalRayPos;
                    transform.rotation = originalRayRot;
                    Debug.LogWarning("left use " + hitLeft.distance);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way better method that makes this work. I changed my method a little bit. Instead of using a variable to store the previous position I have it set up so if a hit is registered by raycast then the transformation doesn't happen but if no hit is detected then the transformation happens. I also modified this code from this original source http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MouseCameraControl

```
    if (horizontalTranslation.isActivated())
    {
        //sets translate to be used for transformation
        float translateX = Input.GetAxis(mouseHorizontalAxisName) * horizontalTranslation.sensitivity;
        //variables for raycasting
        origin = transform.position;
        Vector3 eLeft = -GetComponent<Camera>().transform.right;
        Vector3 eRight = GetComponent<Camera>().transform.right;
        RaycastHit hitLeft;
        RaycastHit hitRight;
        //raycast sent to right
        if (translateX > 0)
        {
            if (Physics.SphereCast(origin, sphereRadius, eRight, out hitRight, maxDistance, layerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal))
            {
                //do nothing if hit is detected
            }
            else
            {
                //transform position if no hit detected
                transform.Translate(translateX, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        //raycast sent to left
        if (translateX < 0)
        {
            if (Physics.SphereCast(origin, sphereRadius, eLeft, out hitLeft, maxDistance, layerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal))
            {
                //transform.Translate(translateX, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.Translate(translateX, 0, 0);
            }
        }    
    }
```